# Retrieving sources of apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is there a way to retrieve the source, ie. contents, of apps scripts stored in Google Drive ?

The Drive API gets me only the metadata of the scripts, no link to the contents.

Same thing with the old Document List API.

I'm willing to use other Google APIS or even basic http clients if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, sorry. It is something Google are working on, so please stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is now possible:

[Importing and Exporting Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export)